# how to return async result from calling function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I'm pretty new to async stuff, and I'm rather stuck on this one.

I'm trying to get the result of a mongo query via mongoose, compare it to another value, and return the comparison result from the run() function.

```
async run() {
        const thisHash = await this.getHashOfElement(url, '.edit-text');
        var latestHash;
        await Invitation.findOne().sort('-updated').exec(async (e, record) => { 
            if(record != undefined) {
                const latestInvitation = record;
                latestHash = latestInvitation.hash;
                console.log("latestHash inside");
                console.log(latestHash);
            } else{
                throw e;
            }
        });
        console.log('latestHash outside:');
        console.log(latestHash);
        return latestHash === thisHash;
    }
```

The run() function always returns false, since it thinks latestHash is undefined when the comparison is made.

I thought it would wait until the findOne() is complete, since I put await in front of it, and then perform the comparison. But the outside console log appears before the inside, and it's undefined.

What do I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consider trying it like this, you need to return a value while using `await` with `.exec()`

Document: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

```
async function run() {
  try {
    const thisHash = await this.getHashOfElement(url, '.edit-text');
    const record = await Invitation.findOne().sort('-updated').exec();

    if (!record || !thisHash)
      throw new Error('no record');

    return Boolean(thisHash === record.hash);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('error: ', error);
  }
}
```

I personally rarely use callback just because I don't want the code look nested too much. In your approach, you need to move that comparison into the callback so the code can execute correctly. And also need to `return await Invitation...`

Comment: Ah wonderful, that worked. Thanks @Duc Hong! I think I was looking for a way to do it without the callback

Comment: Thanks, please mark it as correct answer for future reader who might have same problem like yours.